# Hidden MS Office files, bloated HD?

Tags: hard-drive, microsoft-office, crash, uninstall

At work, we were all getting upgraded to MSOffice Five Million or whatever they're up to. Most people had IT upgrade their computers, I went online and tried to do the upgrade from our company website.  Tried four times, each time it crashed.  Now my HD is mysteriously full, but I see no unusual files.  What's going on, where did MS dump the temporary files?  I never did get the upgrade installed, and there's no "uninstall" option Office, either.  I don't want to scrub my drive and reimage it.

Comment: If you have software on your work computer you cannot replace, talk to IT,   I bet they can.

Comment: It's CS6, off a CD I lost.  To replace it we have to buy it all over again, because Adobe won't allow you to replace lost software.  Jerks.

Comment: It isn't your job to worry about that.  Besides you need to solve that problem, before your HDD does actually need to be reimaged or replaced, sounds like you mucked around with forces you didn't fully understand now that might be required.

Comment: Ummm, it wasn't my fault.  IT mucked up that install, pulled it down before more casualties.

Answer (score 1):

One useful tool for checking what is taking up your HD space is WinDirStat. https://windirstat.info/

You can use it to see what files and folders are taking up the most space and go from there. If you see something strange you can look it up and see if it can be safely removed.